# Importing TypeScript declarations from local, private module into application

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have the following directory layout, leveraging [yarn workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/):

```
package.json
tsconfig.json
packages/
  a/
    package.json   // contains "name": "a" & "version": "1.0.0"
    index.d.ts
  b/
    package.json
    tsconfig.json
    src/
      index.ts
```

Inside `packages/b/tsconfig.json` some very basic rules:

```
{
  extends: 
  compilerOptions: {
    rootDir: src,
    outDir: build
  },
  include: [ **/*.ts ]
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to import the definitions declared in `packages/a/index.d.ts` in `packages/b/src/index.ts` with a statement like `import { Foo } from 'a';`. I want to keep the `index.d.ts` in its own package because I also have a package `c` using the same definitions.

Without any modification the above will throw a "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'a'" error. Therefore, I tried the following:

1. Add `baseUrl: .` and `paths: { a: [ ../a/index.d.ts ] }`, which now fails with "Module build failed: Error: /path/to/packages/a/index.d.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation."
2. Do `yarn workspace b add a@1.0.0`, which symlinked `node_modules/a -> packages/a`. Interestingly, this also resulted in a "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'a'", until I added `main: index.d.ts` to `packages/a/package.json`, after which I once again got "Module build failed: Error: /path/to/packages/a/index.d.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation."
3. Add `../../a/index.d.ts` to `include` in `packages/b/tsconfig.json` after doing 2., which results in the same still. I assume this is because files outside of `rootDir` can't be referenced in `includes`.
4. Replace `rootDir: src` with `rootDirs: [ src, ../a ]` in `packages/b/tsconfig.json`. Same result.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve these compilation errors or avoid them entirely? The only strategy that comes to my mind would be creating a .js entry in package `a` which implements the interfaces of `index.d.ts` and exports them as a module, while `index.d.ts` declares definitions for that module. But I'd prefer to keep only the interfaces shared, instead of implementation details which may differ from package to package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you avoid putting the `.d.ts` file in the `main` field of `package.json` and instead put it in `types`?

**`package.json` for `a`:**

```
{
  "name": "a",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "types": "index.d.ts"
}
```

**`index.js` in `a`:**

```
module.exports = {}
```

During the build TypeScript should pull from the `types` field to pick up the interfaces.  You shouldn't need to do anything special with `rootDir`, `include`, `baseUrl`, etc in the `tsconfig.json`.